# simple ruby method helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just learning ruby and wanting to practice writing little helper methods for rails as a good way of revising the basics. 
all I would like to do is provide a counter for scoped objects.

so in my view i write this

```
=stats_counter_for(with_pending_state)
```

'pending_state' being a particular scope of the model.

```
def stats_counter_for(object_state)
    Photo.object_state.count
end
```

so i want to pass this through to provide a count of all items with a pending state.

so eventually I can do

```
=stats_counter_for(with_active_state)
=stats_counter_for(with_inactive_state)
```

(the equals is from the haml view)

update error message

```
undefined local variable or method `with_pending_state' for #<#<Class:0x007fbce1118230>:0x007fbce1123770>
=link_to '/ Pending Approval', pending_admin_entries_path
=stats_counter_for(with_pending_state)
=link_to '/ Rejected', rejected_admin_entries_path
```

Where am I going wrong here? I am sure this is incredibly simple.

Comment: are you writing this in your application_helper.rb file or your model?

Comment: Could you paste the exact error? if it's in your application helper it should be working

Comment: @Edmund thanks man, here it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send) method:

```
def stats_counter_for(state)
  Photo.send("with_#{state}_state").count
end
```

So in your views you can use it like that:

```
= stats_counter_for(:active) # or as a string 'active'
= stats_counter_for(:inactive)
```

Comment: You could also pass the method name through wholesale: `Photo.send(state).count` and then `stats_counter_for(:with_active_state)`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I think it would be too repetitive if used frequently in the views.

Comment: Yeah, I like your method better, but just mentioning a more generic solution.

Comment: @Stefan What's to stop you from writing `= system('rm -rf /')`, right? Can't protect against the programmer.

Comment: @rico_mac Please, paste the code of your Photo model. If you have defined those scopes, this helper should work.

Comment: @backpackerhh no i just wanted to know where I was going wrong with mine

Comment: @rico_mac you can't pass an arbitrary word like `with_active_state` as an argument (unless it refers to a variable or method). You have to pass a string or symbol instead, e.g. `"with_active_state"` or `:with_active_state`. [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send) then invokes the corresponding method.

Comment: @Stafan, thank you. I get it. Just played around with it in Irb.